# insert into table and a look up table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run these statements:

```
INSERT INTO Attendee (FirstName,LastName,Email) 
VALUES ("Anita","Smith","anits@domain.com");

INSERT INTO Attendee (FirstName,LastName,Email) 
VALUES ("Amber","Lst","alst@domain.com");
```

There are 200 of these...
But I have an xref (look up?) table like this:

```
xrefSomeListIdAndAttendeeIds
XrefId
SomeListId
AttendeeId
```

I want this in the table `xrefSomeListIdAndAttendeeIds`

```
XrefId | SomeListId |  AttendeeId
---------------------------------
   1   |     1      |      1
   2   |     1      |      2
   3   |     1      |      3
```

`SomeListId` is the id of a named list, a list I want the attendees to belong to like "SummerCamp".

AttendeeId is automatically incremented (Microsoft SQL Server).

How can I insert automagically into the `xrefSomeListIdAndAttendeeIds` table once I have inserted all my attendees or once I have inserted each attendee?

Comment: You didn't specify a column for AttendeeId in the Attendee table.  Does it exist?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, AttendeeId exists. It's an automatically incremented field in Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: I don't see an easy way to create your cross reference entry based on your description of the problem unless there's only a single list "SummerCamp".  If so, then it's a simple insert command from a select on Attendee.  When is the list's roster known?  How many lists are there?  Will attendees appear on multiple lists?

Comment: In this case, there is only 1 camp. I know its id (1) and I just need to get over this problem for the customer. Attendees will only belong to "SummerCamp".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, assuming:

- all attendees are on the "SummerCamp" list
- the "SummerCamp" list will have a `SomeListId` value of 1
- `XrefId` in `xrefSomeListIdAndAttendeeIds` is auto-incrementing

Then this statement should work:

```
INSERT INTO xrefSomeListIdAndAttendeeIds
   (SomeListId, AttendeeId)
   SELECT 1, AttendeeId
   FROM Attendee
```

Comment: Bingo! All the assumptions are correct and this is the solution! Thank you very much.